# how do you convert factor into data frame

Tags: r

how do you convert a factor as below to data frame?

```
dput(d)
structure(1L, .Label = "c(\"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\"), c(\"app1\", \"client\", \"org\", \"app1\", \"DATA_CENTER\", \"PURPOSE\", \"REGION\", \"Test\"), c(NA, \"NONE\", \"Host:Environment:test123\", \"111\", \"222\", \"GENERAL\", \"444\", \"555\")", class = "factor")


> d
[1] c("CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS"), c("app1", "client", "org", "app1", "DATA_CENTER", "PURPOSE", "REGION", "Test"), c(NA, "NONE", "Host:Environment:test123", "111", "222", "GENERAL", "444", "555")
Levels: c("CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS"), c("app1", "client", "org", "app1", "DATA_CENTER", "PURPOSE", "REGION", "Test"), c(NA, "NONE", "Host:Environment:test123", "111", "222", "GENERAL", "444", "555")
```

Comment: `as.data.frame(d)` didn't work?

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro, it is putting evertying under one enclosed in c(""). I need each vector to be in rows

Comment: Could you post a picture of `d` instead of `dput`? I didnt understood the format of your data

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro, ok, I also put the output of the d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with the first three lines of code from Duck you can then parse the R code that it was (obviously) `deparse()`-d from:

```
#Code
d1 <- as.character(d)
d1 <- gsub(', c','*c',d1)
d1 <- strsplit(d1,split='\\*')
d1[[1]][2]
#[1] "c(\"app1\", \"client\", \"org\", \"app1\", \"DATA_CENTER\", \"PURPOSE\", \"REGION\", \"Test\")"
```

If you use `lapply` to serially apply aan `eval(parse(text=.)`-function, then you get back an object that can be coerced to a dataframe in long format which your comments suggest you want:

```
setNames(lapply(d1[[1]], function(x) eval(parse(text=x))),paste0("V", 1:3))

$V1
[1] "CONTEXTLESS" "CONTEXTLESS" "CONTEXTLESS" "CONTEXTLESS" "CONTEXTLESS" "CONTEXTLESS"
[7] "CONTEXTLESS" "CONTEXTLESS"

$V2
[1] "app1"        "client"      "org"         "app1"        "DATA_CENTER" "PURPOSE"    
[7] "REGION"      "Test"       

$V3
[1] NA                         "NONE"                     "Host:Environment:test123"
[4] "111"                      "222"                      "GENERAL"                 
[7] "444"                      "555"
```

Thusly:

```
> d2 <- setNames(lapply(d1[[1]], function(x) eval(parse(text=x))),paste0("V", 1:3))
> data.frame( d2[2:3])
           V2                       V3
1        app1                     <NA>
2      client                     NONE
3         org Host:Environment:test123
4        app1                      111
5 DATA_CENTER                      222
6     PURPOSE                  GENERAL
7      REGION                      444
8        Test                      555
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this, and let me know if that works for you. You can coherce as character and then place a common separator for the strings. Here the code:

```
#Code
d1 <- as.character(d)
d1 <- gsub(', c','*c',d1)
d1 <- strsplit(d1,split='\\*')
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,d1))
```

Output for `df` will look like this:

[image]

After some new details, try this using `tidyverse` to separate rows after cleaning them:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
d1 <- as.character(d)
d1 <- gsub(', c','*c',d1)
d1 <- strsplit(d1,split='\\*')
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,d1),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Clean
df$V1 <- gsub('\"','',df$V1)
df$V1 <- gsub("c(","",df$V1,fixed=T)
df$V1 <- gsub(")","",df$V1)
#Format
newdf <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(V1,sep = ',') %>%
  mutate(V1=trimws(V1)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% mutate(Var=paste0('Var.',row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=V1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 9
# Groups:   id [3]
     id Var.1      Var.2      Var.3               Var.4     Var.5     Var.6     Var.7     Var.8    
  <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>               <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1     1 CONTEXTLE~ CONTEXTLE~ CONTEXTLESS         CONTEXTL~ CONTEXTL~ CONTEXTL~ CONTEXTL~ CONTEXTL~
2     2 app1       client     org                 app1      DATA_CEN~ PURPOSE   REGION    Test     
3     3 NA         NONE       Host:Environment:t~ 111       222       GENERAL   444       555
```

Comment: no this will not work. I need each values to be on their own cell

Comment: @user1471980 You want a long vector or each value in a cell?

Comment: each value in cell. In this case, there should be 3 rows 8 columns.

Comment: quick question. I will apply this to a large data set. I expect each c("") have 8 values, in case it is not eight, is there a way to insert "NA"?

Comment: @user1471980 As we are using `pivot_wider()` the function understand that and add `NA` where there are not values!

Comment: @user1471980 Let me know how that goes!

Answer (score 1):

Just `parse` and `eval` the text within a `data.frame(...)`. No need to reinvent the wheel.

```
df <- eval(parse(text = paste0("data.frame(", as.character(d), ")")))
names(df) <- paste0("v", seq_along(df))
```

Output

```
           v1          v2                       v3
1 CONTEXTLESS        app1                     <NA>
2 CONTEXTLESS      client                     NONE
3 CONTEXTLESS         org Host:Environment:test123
4 CONTEXTLESS        app1                      111
5 CONTEXTLESS DATA_CENTER                      222
6 CONTEXTLESS     PURPOSE                  GENERAL
7 CONTEXTLESS      REGION                      444
8 CONTEXTLESS        Test                      555
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_match_all` to extract everything between `c(....)`, split the string on comma and bind the dataset.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(stringr::str_match_all(d, 'c\\((.*?)\\)'), function(x) {
  do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub('"', '',x[, 2]), ',\\s*'))
}))
```

Comment: when I do this, It only grabs first line in the data set. I have thousand of lines.

Comment: this line only captures the first line in d, I need this to apply to whole data set "data <- gsub('"', '', stringr::str_match_all(d, 'c\\((.*?)\\)')[[1]][, 2])", any ideas

Comment: @user1471980 yes, I used `[[1]]` part because `d` is length 1. If you have large data we can use `lapply`/`sapply` to extract 2nd column from each list. See updated answer.